# Highlight point range in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use following code to create a dynamic Highchart using websocket connection. Is there a way to highlight(with some other color) selected range in the graph. For example, If the value from websocket is higher than 25 then those values must be colored differently until value drops below 25.

```
chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8091');

                    connection.onmessage = function (event) {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = parseInt(event.data);
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);


                    };
            //////////////////////////
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Multiple series is a common answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `threshold` in plotOptions and `negativeColor` in series to do that.

```
plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            threshold: 5
        }
    }
```

And

```
series: {
        ...
        color: '#FF0000',
        negativeColor: '#0088FF'
    }
```

Here's an example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r6o0xw4w/)

**EDIT:** You can also use `plotBands` to highlight the background in any range: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotbands-color/)